# cant add camera rotation in gdscript

Tags: gdscript

I'm trying to add camera rotation to my character in Godot, but I keep getting the error "Invalid call to function 'rotated' in base 'Vector3'.Expected 2 arguments" i tried making the direction variable a vector 2, but when i did that the physics function that makes my bean character jump, will not work because there has to be another axis that it can move on
code: (error is from line 58)

```
extends KinematicBody
var damage = 10

var speed = 500
var direction = Vector3()
var gravity = -9.8
var velocity = Vector3()
var sens = 0.2

onready var cam = get_node("Camera")
onready var anim_player = $AnimationPlayer
onready var camera = $Camera
onready var raycast = $Camera/RayCast



func _ready():
    print("hi")


func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        var movement = event.relative
        cam.rotation.x += -deg2rad(movement.y * sens)
        cam.rotation.x = clamp(cam.rotation.x, deg2rad(-45), deg2rad(180))
        rotation.y += -deg2rad(movement.x * sens)


func fire():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Fire"):
        if not anim_player.is_playing():
            if raycast.is_colliding():
                var target = raycast.get_collider()
                if target.is_in_group("enemy"):
                    target.health -=damage
        anim_player.play("AssaultRifleFire")
    else:
        anim_player.stop()







# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    fire()
    
    
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
    if Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_ESCAPE):
            get_tree().quit()
        
        
        
    direction = direction.normalized().rotated(-rotation.y)
    
    
    direction = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Left"):
        direction.z -= 1
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Right"):
        direction.z += 1
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Forward"):
        direction.x += 1


    if Input.is_action_pressed("Back"):
        direction.x -= 1

    

    
    direction = direction.normalized()
    
    direction = direction * speed * delta
    
    if velocity.y > 0:
        gravity = -20
    else:
        gravity = -30
    
    
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    velocity.x = direction.x
    velocity.z = direction.z
    
    
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
    
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_SPACE):
        velocity.y = 10



var speed = 500
var direction = Vector3()
var gravity = -9.8
var velocity = Vector3()
var sens = 0.2

onready var cam = get_node("Camera")
onready var anim_player = $AnimationPlayer
onready var camera = $Camera
onready var raycast = $Camera/RayCast



func _ready():
    print("hi")


func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        var movement = event.relative
        cam.rotation.x += -deg2rad(movement.y * sens)
        cam.rotation.x = clamp(cam.rotation.x, deg2rad(-45), deg2rad(180))
        rotation.y += -deg2rad(movement.x * sens)


func fire():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Fire"):
        if not anim_player.is_playing():
            if raycast.is_colliding():
                var target = raycast.get_collider()
                if target.is_in_group("enemy"):
                    target.health -=damage
        anim_player.play("AssaultRifleFire")
    else:
        anim_player.stop()







# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    fire()
    
    
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
    if Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_ESCAPE):
            get_tree().quit()
        
        
        
    direction = direction.normalized().rotated(-rotation.y)
    
    
    direction = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Left"):
        direction.z -= 1
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Right"):
        direction.z += 1
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Forward"):
        direction.x += 1


    if Input.is_action_pressed("Back"):
        direction.x -= 1

    

    
    direction = direction.normalized()
    
    direction = direction * speed * delta
    
    if velocity.y > 0:
        gravity = -20
    else:
        gravity = -30
    
    
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    velocity.x = direction.x
    velocity.z = direction.z
    
    
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
    
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_SPACE):
        velocity.y = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You require two arguments into the rotated function, see the gdscript manual:

> Vector3 rotated(axis: Vector3, phi: float)
>
> Rotates this vector around a given axis by phi radians. The axis must be a normalized vector.

therefore something like this

`direction = direction.normalized().rotated(Vector3(0,-1,0),rotation.y)`